# Php optimize my request with joins ?

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I come here with a question on mysql query.
I'll try to make it simple and quick (and understandable, because I speak french)
This is my first post on StackOverFlow, which already helped me a lot with all kind of problems so thanks to all the community :)

I am quiet new to php and mysql and I'm writing an iOS application that uses php and mysql.
Here I am using 2 different tables for this example :

-Utilisateurs (users in french) that contains :

- name
- image_name (reference to a profileImage on a server)
- and others fields I'm not using in this example

-Followers, containing :

- user_name (quiet explicit)
- follows (this field contains the name of the user that user_name follows

Here is the query that works perfectly

```
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db(db, $con);


    // By this request I select the users that my current user ($_GET['userName']) follows

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT user_name, follows FROM Followers WHERE user_name = "'.$_GET['userName'].'"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



    //When I find a user that my current user follows, I select his name and the name of the user(s) that user has followed less than 2 days ago

     $user = $row['follows'];
     $res = mysql_query('SELECT user_name, follows, followed_on FROM Followers WHERE user_name = "'.$user.'" AND TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(followed_on) <= 2');



    // Now when I find a user that is followed by the user that my current user follows, I select the profile image linked to his profile

     while($follow = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $img = mysql_query('SELECT image_name FROM Utilisateurs WHERE name = "'.$follow['follows'].'"');
     if(mysql_num_rows($img) != 0){



//And here I echo differents results if a profileImage has been found or not

        $imgProfile = mysql_fetch_row($img);
        echo $follow['user_name'].'$'.$follow['follows'].'$'.$imgProfile[0].'#';
    }else{
        echo $follow['user_name'].'$'.$follow['follows'].'$ #';
    }
 }
}
```

When I execute this query with for example "benben" (my current user) as userName for the $_GET['username'], everything works perfectly, here is the result that i get in my Webbrowser

Simon$Seba$#Simon$Seb$#Simon$benben$307233348488807.jpg#

Here i can see that:

- Simon has followed Seba
- Simon has followed Seb
- Simon has followed benben (me) whose image_name is 307233348488807.jpg

I put all of these in arrays in my iOS application and everything displays properly and works fine.

BUT, that's a lot of queries if I follow many users that are following many other users.
And worse if many users are doing this at the same time.

So i guess I should perform some JOINS in order to execute less queries, but as I am new in php and mysql, I can't figure out how to do. I've already performed some JOINS in queries that were more simple than this one, but this one is confusing to me.

So if someone has some advices for me or could help me performing this request with JOINS, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: can you post your table structure with some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

I would say tell me more about what you are trying to achieve as this could need a more low level optimisation than a simple join fix, what is the logic behind echoing the chain of follows for 2 days? Also if this will be a heavy load app, it is better to use hadoop or some other object oriented database rather than mysql which will be easier to scale up. Let me know

Comment: Hey,

What I need to do is :

- I have users registered in a database
- A user can connect with his password and login
- A user can publish stuffs that can be seen by other users ( There is a news feed that displays the last activities of the users, and that displays the last activities (2days ago) of the users you can follow (by clicking a simple "Follow button on the user's profile)
- SO i want to optimize the query that News feed is using (by the above code)

-And then display all the results from the query by echoing them in my application.

(I'm not trying to make a new facebook haha)

Comment: OK but you are trying to go with recording the activities as a string of multiple events in single table entries, which is basically not levereging the database's capabilities, you need to create a table of "Activity" and enter each activity with the user's id, event time, and target user's id, than start echoing the users' activities at your profile controller according to which user is being viewed. If you ask me why to do this, I have designed and coded a social network myself and this is how I tackled news feed printing myself.

Comment: also while parsing that string you made with your custom identifiers like dollar and hash signs, you might come across problems if you ever parsed them using regular expressions since they are reserved characters. eg $ sign means end of line etc...

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, I was busy all the week end.
Ok I had already thought about creating a table Activities in my database, but didn't do It because it worked as well but I'll follow your advice. It seems more organized.
Following your comment on the data parsing from my database, I guess there is a better way to do that yes, I did as I could with my low PHP level. Do you recommend me to get my data with JSON parsing ? So I don't have to separate all my column values with special characters in the echo ?
Thanks again !

Comment: I recommend you do not use parsing at all. Just normalize your data first, think what goes as a database column entry and what goes to a separate table, because if you think about it, if you are parsing a certain data in a db entry that means you have not normalised it enough, that it could spread to different entries tables further.

Comment: so in a nutshell - ONLY if you jam too much data in one column you will need parsing of that data, separate data in a more organised way so you never parse any data. Here is a good thread to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987893/safely-normalizing-data-via-sql-query Hope this helps!